# Bootstrap navbar make clicked tab to be active

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read other similar posts, but I can't make mine working.
I want to make the clicked tab to be active

So here is how my bootstrap navbar looks like in html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/static/images/logo.png" alt="Prime Solutions"/>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/"><strong>Acasa</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="/software"><strong>Software</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="/hardware"><strong>Hardware</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="/about"><strong>Despre Noi</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Servicii</strong><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/servicii/servicii">Servicii IT&C </a></li>
              <li><a href="/servicii/consultanta">Consultanta IT&C </a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Parteneri</li>
              <li><a href="/parteneri">Partenerii nostri</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="/noutati"><span id="news">Noutati</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, it doesn't work. It only keeps my `Acasa` Tab to be active.
How should I write the script? thanks

This is how the bottom of my `<body>` looks like:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
  ....... 
</script>
```

This the the script I have tried:

```
<script>
  $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  });    
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I figure it out what the problem was. The jQuery works, but when I click, for example, the Software tab, I get redirected to /software and thus, the Software tab doesn't turn on active because of the redirect. This navigation bar appears on each of my pages. So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: sorry, edited. I meant to write addClass. still not working though

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/131048)**

Comment: still not working... I have edited my post to see how I declare my scripts

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in each and every page.

```
$(function() {
var loc = window.location.href;
   $(".navbar .navbar-nav > li").each(function() {
      if (loc.match('/software')) { // software is the name of the page/slug
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        }
   });
});
```

Or else you can use `'if` `else if` conditions, if you are having limited number of pages.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I solved it by coding the logic on the server side. I was too focused about a jQuery solution and couldn;t realize that I can solve this within the server side.

Comment: @Mihai Zamir could you please post your solution of fixing it with in the server side